# How create an utils in Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxtjs 2.15.4 and I wanna revise my Utils. Right now I'm using a mixin as my utils but I wanna do something like this:

```js
import {func1 , func3} from '~/plugins/mixins/utils.js'
export default{
  // ------------
  methods:{
    myMethod(){
      this.func1()
    },
  }
}
```

I also want my utils be like a mixin so I can have access to `this.` ; because I use `this` to access `store` or `$router` or other methods and computed data in my utils.js .

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a plugin and include this in the `nuxt.config.js` file where you 'inject' objects or methods. Now you can also access the (store) context.

```js
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  /* Here we inject the method 'func1' */
  inject('func1', (params) => console.log('This is func1', params))
}
```

and then you can use it like this

```js
methods: {
    myMethod() {
      this.$func1()
    }
}
```

[Here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context) you can read more about inject

Comment: right now i'm using a global mixin and the problem is i dont want to import all of that on init ! instead just import the functions that i need locally in the comonent/page